# How do I use CSF to redirect domain requests to a port?

Tags: centos, firewall, routing, csf

I have a server setup that uses two different webservers with different subdomains. Right now the servers listen on different ports (80 & 4000)

So users don't have to put in :4000 I'd like to have a traffic from a different domain route port 80 traffic to the 4000 port through [CSF](http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html).

I have a wildcard redirect setup so *.mydomain resolves to my server.

Right now it works like this:

- user navigates to http://www.myexample.com and is served a WordPress app.
- user navigates to http://test.exampleDomain2.com:4000 and is served by a custom Node app.
- user navigates to http://testAgain.exampleDomain2.com:4000 and is served by the same custom Node app.

I want it to work the way it does now except enable users to leave off the port.

- ie. http://www.myexample.com = > still served by WordPress
- http://testAgain.exampleDomain2.com => served by custom app (no port 4000 required)

We already have CSF installed so I'd prefer a solution using that.

EDIT: looks like CSF redirects operate on ip addresses not http hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this on web server.
Try with a reverse proxy

Original post: http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/116-simple-apache-reverse-proxy-example